# Puppet fileserver - Could not evaluate

Tags: linux, file, puppet

I am working on trying to copying files from my puppetmaster to my webserver, which is not working.

On my puppetmaster I have edited the file `fileserver.conf` and added:

```
  [extra_files]
  path /etc/puppet/files
   allow *
```

After that, restarted puppetmaster and puppet on the puppetmaster.

I have an test.txt in the `/etc/puppet/files` folder

On the webserver I have this apache2.pp script

```
file { "/test.txt":
                 mode => "600",
                owner => 'root',
                group => 'root',
                ensure => present,
                source => "puppet:///files/test.txt",
        }
```

I am receiving this error, which I am really unsure how to solve:

```
 **Error: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/test.txt]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s)**
```

Hope someone can maybe help me with some steps to troubleshoot what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

According to description in `fileserver.conf`:

```
# [extra_files]
#   path /etc/puppet/files
#   allow *
#
# In the example above, anything in /etc/puppet/files/<file name> would be
# available to authenticated nodes at puppet:///extra_files/<file name>.
#
```

change

```
source => "puppet:///files/test.txt",
```

to

```
source => "puppet:///extra_files/test.txt",
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use file server mounts unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Instead, create a module that holds the file you need to sync, such as module `webserver`

```
mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules/webserver/files
```

In your `file` resource, reference the file as follows:

```
source => 'puppet:///modules/webserver/test.txt'
```

Be careful not to include `files` in the URL of files that are retrieved from within modules.